# glTF Re-Export Vertex Normals Issue

Tags: animation, rigging, normals, vertex-groups, gltf

I've created an animated glb and all works well when exported the *first* time.
problem starts when i import it back to blender and trying to re-export it as glb, after breaking my head and going mad i figured that the vertex normals are to blame.

(i know re-exporting the export sounds dumb but sometime i get glb files that need to amend and re-export as glb..)

does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

[image: before and after]

Comment: Unfortunately a screenshot is not enough information to reproduce the problem on a developer's machine.  Is there a sample model you could share?

Comment: After looking to reproduce the issue with other files i understand that it doesn't happens with every model, could it be something to do with the animation?? maybe the normals get flipped somehow?
you can see also on the 2nd copy that the file size increased dramatically.

original file: mbf.me/ivn1dU
  ___
2nd with error: mbf.me/nrLtwh

Comment: It looks like it is an issue of flipped axis, when applying all transformation and changing all rotations to XYZ Euler seems to fix the shading issues.

Another couple of issues popped up:
1. File size increase from 8mb to 20mb ?
2. origin of the model is at the centre of the model, and not able to change it to world centre.

thanks for any help

Comment: This sounds like a bug: I would file an issue at https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues.